# How to apply -= to a string?

Tags: c#, string

I want to have a button which adds "`Text`" to a string which says "`Test`". The outcome would be "`TestText`". Now I press a another button which adds "`Code`". So now the string looks like this: "`TestTextCode`". Now for my problem: I want it so that if I press the first Button again, the "`Text`" dissapears, so only "`TestCode`" would be left. I know you can do `+=` do add text, but is there something similiar like `-=` to delete specific text from a string?

Comment: Do you want to remove all instances of the string from the text?

Comment: Yes, in my case thats what I am aiming for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string test = "";
test = test.Replace("Text", "");
```

Comment: this is what I was going to say

Comment: but this removes all occurences of "Text" is that desired?

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler in case you would want to replace something dynamically you could add a variable string with what you want to replace instead of the "text". Ending up like: `test.Replace(myReplaceString,"");`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) if you want to use `-=` syntax, f.e.

```
string textString = "Text";
string codeString = "Code";

var textBuilder = new StringBuilder("Test"); // "Test"
// simulate the text-button-click:
textBuilder.Append(textString); // "TestText"  
// simulate the code-button-click:
textBuilder.Append(codeString); // "TestTextCode"  
// simulate the remove-text-button-click:
textBuilder.Length -= textString.Length; // "TestText"  
// simulate the remove-code-button-click:
textBuilder.Length -= codeString.Length; // "Test"
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/CTfm9t)

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. You'd need to either use `String.Substring` with appropriate parameters, or `String.Replace` to cut this out. Note that the latter may get complicated if the original string already contains `Text`.

Your best bet is probably to store the unadorned string in a field/variable, and then just deal with rendering it with or without the `Text` and `Code` suffixes according to two flags recording the button states.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an undo, then keep previous version. Strings are immutable, so you're creating new one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you could check with endsWith if the input in at the end and create a new string with substring

Answer (score 0):

there is no operator on string like you have described. On the otherhand, you can use `Replace` function.

```
string s = "TestTextCode";
s = s.Replace("Text", "");
```