# removing a specific string from a label c#

Tags: c#, .net

when i check the first checkBox a "hello " string is assigned to the label text then i check the second checkBox to add the string "world" so label's text becomes "hello world" , the problem if i unchecked the second checkBox i cant remove the string "world" , here is the code :

```
public void checkBox1_Checked(){
     if(checkBox1.checked == true){
         label1.text = "hello ";
     }

}
public void checkBox2_Checked(){
     if(checkBox2.checked == true){
         label1.text += "world";
     }
     else{    //here is the problem
         label1.text -= "world";
     }
}
```

how can i remove the string "world" so label's text becomes only "hello " ?

Comment: Use the [`String.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1) method. The `String` class doesn't override the `-=` operator like it does `+=`. Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281117/how-to-apply-to-a-string) probably makes this a duplicate.

Comment: Your code has some weirdness.  If someone checks cb2, then (assuming `label1` started blank), `label1` will become "world",  If someone then checks cb1, it will change to "hello".  If you then uncheck cb2, you will try to remove "world" from the string "hello".

Comment: @Jesse i actually know that information i was just trying to make my question clear , maybe i did it in the wrong way , thanks anyway

Comment: @Flydog57 yes its true i know , i had to ask the question that way just to know how to remove any string from a label , sorry for that

Comment: The thing about `+=` and `-=` with strings is that `+=` will always succeed (give or take running out of memory).  String concatenation is a pretty common thing to do.  But, what would `-=` mean.  If I have a string like `s = "requires ui changes";` and I try to do `s -= "ui";`, what should the code do: 1) nothing, there's no "ui" at the end, 2) remove the "ui" in "requires", or 3) figure out that I meant the standalone "ui" in the middle?

Comment: @Flydog57 i believe the answer is one there is no "ui" string because the string is "requires ui changes" , i got that thank you , but what if i said ( label1.text -= "requires ui changes" ; ) or (label1.text -= s ; )  , is -= operator here would work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume un-checking checkBox1 should remove "Hello"?

Here's an approach that takes care of all four possibilities..."", "Hello", "Hello World", and "World":

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fooBar();
}

private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fooBar();
}

private void fooBar()
{
    label1.Text = (checkBox1.Checked ? "Hello" : "") +
        (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked ? " " : "") + 
        (checkBox2.Checked ? "World" : "");
}
```

If the ORDER of "Hello" and "World" is not important, then perhaps this is more to your liking?

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        label1.Text += (label1.Text.Length == 0 ? "" : " ") + "Hello";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = label1.Text.Replace("Hello", "").Trim();
    }
}

private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox2.Checked)
    {
        label1.Text += (label1.Text.Length == 0 ? "" : " ") + "World";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = label1.Text.Replace("World", "").Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could coalesce this into a single handler as well (point both the `checkBox1,CheckChanged` and `checkBox2,CheckChanged` events to a single handler).  It could take the roll of `fooBar` in the code above.  If you needed to figure out which checkbox changed (which you don't here), you could look at `sender`

Comment: @Flydog57 Absolutely.  It's just harder to show in code that both checkboxes fire the same handler without adding a bunch more to the post, so I left them separated.

Comment: my comment was more for the OP's benefit than for yours.

Comment: @Idle_Mind i believe the second option for me is more likely , in this case if i check any checkBox the word will displayed then if i unchecked one of them the word will be removed so this will achieve all the possibilities : "hello world" , "world hello" , "hello" , "world" , ""

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Replace`.

```
label1.Text = label.Text.Replace("world", String.Empty);
```

`+=` on a string is a shortcut for `s = s + "something"`.
I've never seen a programming language where you can remove the word from the end.

There are more complexities if the word is repeated. "hello world world" would become "hello ". You can look for `TrimEnd` solutions if you want to just remove a string from the end of another string.

Comment: I would put a space before world so that multiple clicks doesn't end up with multiple spaces.